# How do I sort on the first column every 4 lines in a file with a key in the second column

Tags: linux, text-processing, sort

Example File :

first column can have **fixed set of 4 unordered values** `world1.com,world2.com,world3.com or world4.com`

second column is a key belongs to each line such that each of the four sets has unique random key.

```
world4.com           /randomkeyhghgdh778/key67567
world1.com           /randomkeygahjuh572/key639839
world2.com           /randomkey788gauh72/key63whjk
world3.com           /randomkey788gauh72/key63whjk
world1.com           /randomkeyhueh34778/key67uuu77
world4.com           /randomkey8998382/key6hh77686
world3.com           /randomkey7HHHH0000/key6333355k
world2.com           /randomkeyJJJJ1111/key63333
```

and so on

Desired Output:

```
world1.com           /randomkeygahjuh572/key639839
world2.com           /randomkey788gauh72/key63whjk
world3.com           /randomkey788gauh72/key63whjk
world4.com           /randomkeyhghgdh778/key67567
world1.com           /randomkeyhueh34778/key67uuu77
world2.com           /randomkeyJJJJ1111/key63333
world3.com           /randomkey7HHHH0000/key6333355k
world4.com           /randomkey8998382/key6hh77686
```

Comment: does each first column have the same number of key lines?

Comment: yes,for example in the first set `world1.com` coresponds to one key line `/randomkeygahjuh572/key639839` in the second set `world1.com` coresponds to one key line `/randomkeyhueh34778/key67uuu77` and so on

Comment: how big is the file? am learning Perl, so worked out a solution in Perl, should I post that?

Comment: you can post it in perl. i am learning as well but i am writing this in shell script so i wuold prefer a shell/bash sol.

Comment: For world2 and world3, you show numbers sorting before letters.  For world4, then, shouldn't `/randomkey89...` sort before `/randomkeyhg...`?

Comment: I am not caring about the second column i only want to sort the first column but the keys should match for each line when sorting first column..there is a one to one mapping for each set of world1.com,world2.com,world3.com or world4.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To organize the files by world:

```
$ paste -d'\n' <(grep world1 file) <(grep world2 file) <(grep world3 file) <(grep world4 file)
world1.com           /randomkeygahjuh572/key639839
world2.com           /randomkey788gauh72/key63whjk
world3.com           /randomkey788gauh72/key63whjk
world4.com           /randomkeyhghgdh778/key67567
world1.com           /randomkeyhueh34778/key67uuu77
world2.com           /randomkeyJJJJ1111/key63333
world3.com           /randomkey7HHHH0000/key6333355k
world4.com           /randomkey8998382/key6hh77686
```

#### How it works

We can use `grep` to select the lines for each world:

```
$ grep world4 file
world4.com           /randomkeyhghgdh778/key67567
world4.com           /randomkey8998382/key6hh77686
```

`paste` combines lines from multiple files.  The paste command could look like this:

```
paste -d'\n' file1 file2 file3 file3.
```

We don't actually have to create true files for each world.  Instead, we can create file-like objects for each one using *process substitution*:

```
paste -d'\n' <(grep world1 file) <(grep world2 file) <(grep world3 file) <(grep world4 file)
```

*Process substitution* is supported by bash, zsh, and AT&T ksh88 and ksh93 but not dash, pdksh, or mksh.

#### Extra feature: sorting by key

To illustrate the flexibility of this approach, we will sort the keys for each world.  **Note: sorting breaks up sets of lines.  Do not use this if you want to keep sets together.**

We can separate the worlds using `grep`, and then `sort` each one, and then merge the lines back together using `paste`:

```
$ paste -d'\n' <(grep world1 file | sort -k2,2) <(grep world2 file | sort -k2,2) <(grep world3 file | sort -k2,2) <(grep world4 file | sort -k2,2)
world1.com           /randomkeygahjuh572/key639839
world2.com           /randomkey788gauh72/key63whjk
world3.com           /randomkey788gauh72/key63whjk
world4.com           /randomkey8998382/key6hh77686
world1.com           /randomkeyhueh34778/key67uuu77
world2.com           /randomkeyJJJJ1111/key63333
world3.com           /randomkey7HHHH0000/key6333355k
world4.com           /randomkeyhghgdh778/key67567
```

Note that `sort` depends on locale.  Different `locales` may result in different orders.

Comment: It works well for the above example ,if i have a 1000 lines, one question will this intermingle the sets of line  `world1.com,world2.com,world3.com or world4.com`  with another set or each set will be seperate after sort

Comment: If you have 1,000 lines, then there would be 250 of each world.  The last four lines in the output would be the 250th world1 line, followed by the 250th world2, followed by the 250th world3 line, followed by the 250th world4 line.  Is that what you mean by keeping sets together?

Comment: yes ,correct that's what i mean

Comment: @munish Very good.

Comment: This will get cumbersome with large "sets" but +1 for thinking out of the box.

Comment: Worth noting is that `<()` is non-POSIX, so this won't work in `sh`, so you may want to fiddle your shebangs if you want to put this in scripts.

Comment: @ymbirtt Good point.  I added a sentence shell compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

This `perl` script should work with any number of domains (first fields) with any number of keys (second fields) per domain.  Domains **may** have the same number of keys each, but don't have to.

It builds up a hash (`%domains`) with each element of the hash containing an array of keys.  While doing that, it keeps track of the largest number of keys seen for any of the domains.

After reading all the input, it prints each key that exists for each domain.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %domains = ();
my $numkeys = 0;

while(<>) {
  chomp;
  my ($domain, $key) = split;
  push @{ $domains{$domain} }, $key;

  # find the largest number of keys for any domain
  $numkeys = scalar @{ $domains{$domain} } if (scalar @{ $domains{$domain} } gt $numkeys);
}

for my $keynum (0..$numkeys-1){
    foreach my $domain (sort keys %domains) {
        print "$domain\t$domains{$domain}[$keynum]\n" if (defined($domains{$domain}[$keynum]));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
world1.com  /randomkeygahjuh572/key639839
world2.com  /randomkey788gauh72/key63whjk
world3.com  /randomkey788gauh72/key63whjk
world4.com  /randomkeyhghgdh778/key67567
world1.com  /randomkeyhueh34778/key67uuu77
world2.com  /randomkeyJJJJ1111/key63333
world3.com  /randomkey7HHHH0000/key6333355k
world4.com  /randomkey8998382/key6hh77686
```

If failing to have the same number of keys is meant to be regarded as an error, replace the `print "$domain\.....` line in the last code block with:

```perl
if (defined($domains{$domain}[$keynum])) {
    print "$domain\t$domains{$domain}[$keynum]\n"
} else {
    warn "$domain is missing a key\n";
};
```

replace `warn` with `die` if you want that to be a fatal error.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie;
use open qw< :encoding(ASCII) >;

my $filename = $ARGV[0];
my ($ip_fh, $op_fh);
open($ip_fh, "<", $filename);
open($op_fh, ">", "$filename".".sorted");
my @ip_lines = <$ip_fh>;

for(my $i = 0; $i <= $#ip_lines; $i++)
{
    print $op_fh sort @ip_lines[$i..($i+3)];
    $i += 3;
}

close($ip_fh);
close($op_fh);
```

give input file name as command line argument, ex:

```
./sort_blocks.pl data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{l=l+1; ln[$1]=$0; if (l%4==0) { \
       printf ("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", ln["world1.com"], ln["world2.com"], ln["world3.com"], ln["world4.com"]); \
       delete ln; l=0; } } ' test.txt 
world1.com           /randomkeygahjuh572/key639839
world2.com           /randomkey788gauh72/key63whjk
world3.com           /randomkey788gauh72/key63whjk
world4.com           /randomkeyhghgdh778/key67567
world1.com           /randomkeyhueh34778/key67uuu77
world2.com           /randomkeyJJJJ1111/key63333
world3.com           /randomkey7HHHH0000/key6333355k
world4.com           /randomkey8998382/key6hh77686
```

Answer (score 0):

On GNU system:

```
$ NL='
'
$ <file xargs -n4 -d "$NL" sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$@" | sort' sh
world1.com           /randomkeygahjuh572/key639839
world2.com           /randomkey788gauh72/key63whjk
world3.com           /randomkey788gauh72/key63whjk
world4.com           /randomkeyhghgdh778/key67567
world1.com           /randomkeyhueh34778/key67uuu77
world2.com           /randomkeyJJJJ1111/key63333
world3.com           /randomkey7HHHH0000/key6333355k
world4.com           /randomkey8998382/key6hh77686
```

You can use `$'\n'` instead of `"$NL"` if your shell supported.